# i was trying to change color of scrollbar from angular material sidenav

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I was trying to customize the style of the scrollbar angular material sidenav element to match my design, and i am stuck doing it

Explanation: To remove the default style of blue background color, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrQr9.png)

Answer (score 0):

after some time of searching, I

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: grey;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px #707070;
}
```

```html
  <mat-sidenav class="sidenav navy-bg" mode="side" opened></mat-sidenav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
/* width */
mat-drawer-content.mat-drawer-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
mat-drawer-content.mat-drawer-content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
mat-drawer-content.mat-drawer-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
mat-drawer-content.mat-drawer-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b30000; 
}
```